# Interface pattern in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I was reading some code and one of the recurring patterns is as follows:

```
export interface IA {
    readonly IB: IB
}

export interface IB extends IA {
    name: string;
    dislayName: string;
}
```

What is the advantage of have an interface with a single readonly interface property and then having another interface extend it? Is this a common design pattern? Also, there is a circular type reference. Why is that not throwing an error?

Comment: That depends on how that property is being used. It makes sense if, say, this interface is used for things that can be displayed, and all these things need a particular CSS class when they are read-only. Or maybe if these are things that can be written to a database, except if they are read-only. Really depends on what these things are being used for.

Answer (score 0):

you could model something where you give information eg. about the parent hierarchy.

```
const bla: IA = {
    name: '1st level',
    displayName: '1st',
    IB: {
        name: '2nd level',
        displayName: '2nd',
        IB: {
            name: '3rd level',
            displayName: '3rd',
            IB: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is NOT typescript conform as the IB always needs to be defined (until infinity) - so you cant define it yourself unless you tell typescript to ignore it. What I suspect is that its a typing for some kind of response from the server where it is unknown how deep the structure will be.

I guess the correct interface should be (if my understandings are correct)

```
export interface IB extends Partial<IA> {
    name: string;
    dislayName: string;
}
```

this would allow deep nesting of information